# Expand PSobjects to export to csv

Tags: csv, powershell

How can I convert the `PSobjects` returned by `Get-Help` to strings and export to csv?.  I think this is an easy one, but I can't quite get the format I'm looking for. From reading previous answers, I was trying:

```
Get-Help Get-Content | Select-Object -First 1 -Property @{
    Name="temp"
    Expression = { $_.Name,$_.Synopsis,$_.syntax,$_.Description }
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty temp
```

Which is almost what I want, except it looks like the fields are arrays not strings.  I am trying to have just one string for each element, ie (Name, Synopsis, Syntax, etc).

If I try to export that to csv, I get the lengths of the objects instead of the objects themselves:

```
Get-Help Get-Content | Select-Object -First 1 -Property @{
    Name="temp"
    Expression = { $_.Name,$_.Synopsis,$_.syntax,$_.Description }
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty temp | export-csv -NoType -Path $env:HOME\test.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to export each property in a seperate column (your script currently only exports one). To do this, you have to select each property. For `Syntax` and `Description` I used the `Out-String` cmdlet to convert it to a string and removed all `\r\n` to get a valid CSV:

```
Get-Help Get-Content | Select-Object -First 1 |
    Select-Object Name, Synopsis, 
        @{l='Syntax'; e={($_.Syntax | out-string) -replace "`r?`n"}}, 
        @{l='Description '; e={($_.Description | out-string)-replace "`r?`n"}} |
    Export-Csv -Path $env:HOME\test.txt -NoTypeInformation
```